# Expo Snack: _firebase.default.firestore is not a function

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I made a service in my React Native Expo Snack app that handles the instantiation of different firebase services. Somehow, Snack isn't able to find firestore, as it says "_firebase.default.firestore is not a function". The code used is shows below:

```
import firebase, { firestore } from 'firebase';

const config = { ... // Deleted, assume the config is correct }

export const FirebaseApp = !firebase.apps.length ? firebase.initializeApp(config) : firebase.app();

export const Firestore = firebase.firestore();

export const Auth = firebase.auth();
```

Can somebody confirm this should work in Snack? Why doesn't it recognize firestore() as a function?

Comment: Which version of `firebase` library are you using? Some tutorials might be outdated since they changed how you import difference services a while ago. Please refer to [library docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase#include-only-the-features-you-need) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm using firebase 5.8.1.